# In Java, how to improve performance of object creation?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, object

Object creation is a bottleneck in my application.

I think that adding more threads for object creation makes the situation worse, because object creation is a CPU-bound task, right?

Then, how to improve performance?

Comment: What indicates *object creation* is the overhead? Is there some performance analysis to back this assumption? If there is no analysis, then *stop trying to "fix" what hasn't been shown as an issue* :-) (A modern JVM/machine can create [and GC] *hundreds of millions* of new objects per second.)

Comment: If indeed the object creation is a problem (I agree with @pst that you should use some sort of measure to asser this), then adding more threads is not gonna solve the problem. You should look into creating less objects or simplifying their creation.

Comment: Unless you are using JVM v1.1 and/or creating literally many thousands of objects a second, I really doubt that object creation is a bottleneck for you, since this is one of the most optimized features of the JVM.

If this really is causing you a problem, use an Object Pool.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Its process is simple. The whole process is just getting lines from network and converting each line into object including almost hundred objects. And number of lines per a second is 10,000. That made me have the conclusion. Based on your opinion, I'm wrong. I have to find the bottleneck somewhere else. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Don't assume that object creation is your problem, but also don't assume that it is _not_ your problem. You should profile your object creation. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457059/how-to-profile-object-creation-in-java) for info on how to do it.

Comment: @JohnnyLim I would *imagine* the bottleneck is then IO (or parsing) related. Do start with a benchmark/performance analysis though -- then the parts that *could* be improved (in a way that is an improvement for the entire system) can be identified :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the problem is not object creation itself, but repeated object creation and garbage generation. That causes two performance hits: creating all those objects and extra garbage collection stalls.

First, you should use profiling tools to verify that excessive object creation is the source of your performance problems. Assuming that you have verified that this is the problem, there are various things to look for and strategies to try. It all depends on how your code is written, so there's no one recommendation that will work. This list of [Java performance guidelines from IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/java_perf_guide.htm) is definitely worth applying. It identifies how to avoid many of the most common sins: don't create objects inside loops; use StringBuilder instead of a series of string concatenation expressions; use primitive types and avoid auto-boxing/unboxing where possible; cache frequently used objects; allocate collection classes with an explicit capacity instead of allowing them to grow; etc.

Another nice resource is Chapter 4 of the book Java Performance Tuning. (You can read it on-line [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html).)

If you search the web for *excessive object creation java*, you can find lots of other recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get significant performance improvement by multi-threading CPU bound tasks when your app is running on a machine with multiple processors.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pst says - are you sure it's the bottleneck? because these days it's not a common one.

But given that. One thing you could try is avoiding creation by caching and reusing instances. But that totally depends on what your program does.

Comment: Pooling and reusing objects sound nice although I can't judge whether my object is worth to reuse or not yet :-)

Comment: @JohnnyLim The only way to know is to profile your application.  If in doubt, I would do what you feel is the clearest and simplest which usually means not recycling.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses a TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffer) for small to medium sizes objects.  This means each thread can allocate objects concurrently. i.e. you don't get a slow down for using multiple threads.

In general, more CPUs improve CPU-bound problems. Its IO bound tasks where one cpu can use all the available bandwidth, like disk access, which are no faster when you use multiple CPUs.

The simplest way to reduce the cost of Object Creation is to create/discard less objects.  There is a common assumption that object creation is unavoidable, but the last 2.5 years I have worked on applications which GC less than once per day, even under production load.

Most application don't work this way because they don't need to. However, if you have a need to minimise object creation you can.